# Dynamic button causes Unexpected Token

Tags: html, button

I am trying to dynamically add a button using an array gathered from database information.  Upon clicking the button, I want several temporary variables to be set from the array

```
comp += '<button onclick="tempData=' + array["data"] + '">';
comp += array["button_name"];
comp += '</button>';
```

The problem I have is when the **array["data"]** result ends with a dash.  In this instance, I get an Unexpected Token error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by instead using a data- attribute in the html, assigning the information from the array there instead, and then passing the button with my onclick

```
comp += '<button data-myInfo="' + array["data"] + '">';
comp += ' onclick="doSomething(this)">';
comp += array["button_name"];
comp += '</button>';
```